# Uncaught ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined

Tags: deno

Trying to run deno locally for a deno deploy app which supports [broadcast channel](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-broadcast-channel) but getting this compilation error how do I fix it?

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('')
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined
```

Comment: what `deno` version are you using? `deno 1.14.1v>` versions supports BroadcastChannel

Comment: 1.17 I'm pretty sure I just needed to set --unstable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the stable docs for v`1.17.1`, so shouldn't need `--unstable` to use it:

[https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable@v1.17.1/~/BroadcastChannel](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable@v1.17.1/%7E/BroadcastChannel)

> Compare with unstable: https://doc.deno.land/deno/unstable@v1.17.1

However, in reality that's not the case:

```
$ deno
Deno 1.17.1
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> new BroadcastChannel()
Uncaught ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:1
> close()
$ deno --unstable
Deno 1.17.1
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> new BroadcastChannel()
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'BroadcastChannel': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
    at Object.requiredArguments (deno:ext/webidl/00_webidl.js:627:13)
    at new BroadcastChannel (deno:ext/broadcast_channel/01_broadcast_channel.js:81:14)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
> close()
```

You can file an issue in [the repo](https://github.com/denoland/deno).

Edit: Issue created: [denoland/deno#13214](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13214)

Answer (score 0):

To follow-up on this, it's 2023, the issue above was resolved, but `BroadcastChannel` is still unstable (under the `--unstable` flag).

It's also worth noticing that `BroadcastChannel` can only broadcast events for the other `BroadcastChannel` instances created on the same process.

For example, if you have two scripts that create channels with the same name (`new BroadcastChannel('same-channel-name')`, those processes won't be able to communicate with each other